# Tuned RF circuit: How to minimise interference?

Tags: rf, interference, tuning

The circuit in Figure 1 is designed to detect an RF signal at f0=40kHz. For information, this will be a portable proximity sensor, worn on a cat's collar, so it has be small and light.

The circuit detects 40kHz, but it also 'detects' almost any other piece of electrical equipment. My question is this: how can I ensure this circuit will pick up only 40kHz?

A subsidiary question is: if an LC tank circuit (at amp1) is better than an RC active filter (at amp2) at filtering signals, should I be using an LC tank circuit with amp2 (and vice versa)?

[image]
Figure 1.

The circuit is on a breadboard, so there are many connection wires on the breadboard which could pick up stray signals. However, removing the 18cm aerial eliminates the spurious activations at the output (F), which suggests the interference is not being picked up primarily by those breadboard connection wires (removing the aerial also prevents detection of my 40kHz signal).

**Overview of the circuit.**

The aerial has to be very short. The IC is a quad TLC274CN op amp. Amp1 uses the LC tank circuit to differentially amplify RF at 40kHz.

Amp2 is an active filter, using RC components centred on 40kHz, with a lower cut-off frequency of f1=30kHz and an upper cut-off frequency of f2=50kHz.

Amp3 just isolates all those RC components around amp2 from the rest of the circuit (and adds in some amplification with feedback resistor R5).
Amp3's output is rectified and smoothed before being fed to amp4.

Amp4 is a comparator, which compares amp3's output with a DC value set by the 50k variable resistor. The output from amp4 switches a transistor on/off which drives a buzzer (I have it connected to an LED instead now).

The RF at 40kHz  is generated by an Arduino using a long stretch of speaker wire as a transmission antenna.

Comment: What did you not learn from my answer to your previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feeding an antenna raw into an amplifier input invites nonlinear behavior, leading to interference. I suggest replacing R1 with a parallel LC resonator, tuned to 40 kHz.

Speaking of tuning, I don't see any way to tune your filter. It's going to be too touchy to count on components off the shelf to resonate at exactly 40 kHz.

Comment: Thanks. Presumably the suggested parallel LC resonator is intended to prevent RF at 40kHz escaping to ground. Wrt tuning, I measured the resonant frequency with  an oscillosope using the tank circuit in series with  a resistor.

Comment: It's more to give *other* frequencies a way to ground. Normally, you tune a resonator like this in circuit, by adjusting to get the highest output amplitude. Be sure any nearby metal is in place, as that affects tuning.